# using group by and condition on value of a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table like this:

```
id    tr_id   type
1       1      1        
2       1      1        
3       2      1        
4       2      2        
5       4      1        
6       4      1
7       3      1
8       3      2
9       5      1
```

I want to get all `tr_id` (`group by` this column) that just have `type` **1** and there isn't exist any records that `type` value be **2** **3** **4**...

the result of my table must be:

```
tr_id
  1

  4

  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there is no negative numbers in type column

```
select tr_id   
from yourtable 
group by tr_id   
Having sum(distinct type) = 1
```

If `type` column can have negative numbers then

```
select tr_id   
from yourtable 
group by tr_id   
Having sum(type) = count(case when type = 1 then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

YourModel::select('tr_id)->groupBy('tr_id')->where('tr_id',1)->get();